# How to prevent saving same named file on CouchDb?

Tags: c#-4.0, couchdb

I am using CouchDB with Divan - C# interfacing library for CouchDb.

A file can be uploaded many times on CouchDb. Every time the "id" is changed after file is uploaded, but the "rev" remains the same.
This happens even if all custom attributes defined for file being uploaded are same any existing file on CouchDb with same name.

Is there any way that can avoid uploading same named file if all custom attributes are same? Fetching all files and checking them for file name repetition could be a way, but definitely not preferable for its required time depending on other factors.

Thanking you.

Comment: The id of the file is changed or a new document is generated for this file.

Comment: Thanks Alexis for the reply. But I want to avoid the same uploading same named file if all custom attributes are same. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 3 attributes for a file :

- name
- size in bytes
- Date of modification

I see two main possibilities to avoid duplicates in your database.

#### Client approach

You query the database to check if the document with the same attributes exists with a view. If it's not existing, create it.

#### User defined id

You could generate an id from the attributes as this [library](https://github.com/jo/docuri) is doing.

For example, if my document has those attributes :

`"name":"test.txt",
"size":"512",
"lastModified":"2016-11-08T15:44:29.563Z"`

You could build a unique id like this :
 `"_id":"test.txt/2016-11-08T15:44:29.563Z/512"`